# Define an 'inner product' with AngleBracket

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I want to define my own little 'Inner Product' function satisfying properties of linearity and commutativity, and I'd like to use the "$\langle$" and "$\rangle$" symbols to output my results.  For this I am using `AngleBracket` which has no built-in meaning.

I was able to use `SetAttributes[AngleBracket,Orderless]` to give my inner product the property of commutativity.  $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$.

Then I am able to inconsistently get the AngleBracket to distribute over addition using for example `Distribute[AngleBracket[u+v,w]]`

But I am at a loss to impose the conditions $\langle a v, w\rangle=a\langle v,w \rangle$ where $a$ satisfies `NumericQ[a]==True`, and especially $\langle 0,v\rangle = 0$.

How can do this?  Do I need to write my own 'myInnerProductSimplify' function?

Comment: this could be a start: `Format[bk[a_, b_]] = AngleBracket[a, b]`; `bk[a_ u_, v_] := a bk[u, v] /; NumericQ[a]`; `bk[b_, a_ + c__] := bk[b, a] + bk[b, c]`

Comment: By definition, the arguments of an inner product have to be elements of the same vector space. Because `0` is not the same as `{0}` which is not the same as `{0,0}`, which is not the same as (say) an $L^2$ integrable complex-valued function on a space--all of which could be considered vectors--*it should not be the case* that $\langle 0,v\rangle = 0$: that expression is, in general, nonsensical. To avoid hidden surprises, consider creating an appropriate `vector` type and defining `AngleBracket` as a (sesquilinear) bivariate function of `vector`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question it can be deduced that you're interested only in the Euclidean scalar product for real vector spaces, so I'll make that assumption.

In version 9, I think the cleanest way to do the symbolic manipulations you're after is to use the new capabilities of `TensorReduce`. The special case of a null vector does require care because the product of the scalar $0$ with a vector is evaluated by *Mathematica* to yield $0$ which should then be interpreted as the null vector. This causes no problems if we define `AngleBracket` to yield zero for such $0$ arguments. So the following works if we make a decision at the outset what symbols we will assume to represent vectors - here I add that to the global variable `$Assumptions`:

```
AngleBracket[0, y_] := 0
AngleBracket[x_, 0] := 0
AngleBracket[x_, y_] := Dot[x, y]

Clear[dim]; 
$Assumptions = 
a ∈ Vectors[dim, Reals] && b ∈ Vectors[dim, Reals];
```

Now some tests:

```
AngleBracket[3 a, b] == 3 AngleBracket[a, b] // TensorReduce

(* ==> True *)

Assuming[x ∈ Reals, 
 TensorReduce[AngleBracket[x a, b] == x AngleBracket[a, b]]]

(* ==> True *)

Assuming[x ∈ Reals, 
 TensorReduce[AngleBracket[a, x b] == x AngleBracket[a, b]]]

(* ==> True *)
```

So to do the simplifications in the above equations, one wraps them in `TensorReduce`. The scalar `x` is introduced through an additional assumption which I could have added to `$Assumptions`, too.

The use of `AngleBracket` instead of purely the built-in `Dot` is still useful here because it allows me to handle the special case involving the null vector. For that I personally prefer to use `BraKet`, by the way, because it only requires a single escape sequence to get the template for both factors of the scalar product.

Comment: +1 for `TensorReduce` and `Vectors` -- I hadn't run across these yet.

Answer (score 2):

If I set

```
SetAttributes[AngleBracket, Orderless];
AngleBracket[a_?NumericQ u_, v_] := a AngleBracket[u, v];
```

then I get

```
2 AngleBracket[u, 6 v] == AngleBracket[3 u, 4 v]
(* -> True *)
```

Comment: +1 because this does solve the question as it was posed.

Answer (score 1):

For a starter, I would use a function `angleExpand` like this:

```
SetAttributes[AngleBracket, Orderless];
ruAB = {
  AngleBracket[a_ (k_?NumericQ), b_] :> k AngleBracket[a, b],
  AngleBracket[(k_?NumericQ) a_, b_] :> k AngleBracket[a, b],
  AngleBracket[a_, (k_?NumericQ) b_] :> k AngleBracket[a, b],
  AngleBracket[a_, b_ (k_?NumericQ)] :> k AngleBracket[a, b]
  }

angleExpand[expr_] := Expand[expr //. ruAB]
```

Then:

```
AngleBracket[7u, v 5]
% //angleExpand
```

will give:

```
<7 u,5 v>  
35 <u,v>
```

Comment: Given that `AngleBracket` and `Times` are orderless you should only need one of those 4 rules I believe (untested)

Comment: @Rojo That's a good point. Although the OP hasn't asked for it, in general an [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form#Generalization) is *sesquilinear,* not bilinear, so it may be of use to illustrate a solution--as here--that would apply in full generality.