# How do I simplify a vector expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I am doing vector analysis. I have figured out that the following expression won't be simplified in *Mathematica*:

```
Simplify[Dot[x, y] - Dot[y, x]]
```

I think the reason is that x and y could be matrices, so generally the operation does not commute.  But for a vector, the commutation relation should hold. What I don't know is how to tell *Mathematica* to consider x and y to be vectors.

Also, how can I expand `Cross[x + y, z]` to be `Cross[x, y] + Cross[y, z]`? I tried to use `Expand` and `ExpandAll` but neither worked.

BTW, in *Mathematica*, is it possible to define a abstract row/column vector without explicitly specifying the number of entries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way to do all the things you asked for automatically, independently of *Mathematica* version. The approach relies on a special symbol to identify when we're dealing with a vector: Instead of using things like `x`, `y` etc. for vectors, the convention now is that vectors are written as `vec[x]`, `vec[y]`, etc.

You could also define the wrapper `OverVector[x]` for this purpose because it displays as $\vec{x}$. But for this post I want to keep it simple, and the arrows wouldn't display easily in the source code below.

```
ClearAll[scalarProduct, vec]; 
SetAttributes[scalarProduct, {Orderless}]
vec /: Dot[vec[x_], vec[y_]] := scalarProduct[vec[x], vec[y]]
vec /: Cross[vec[x_], HoldPattern[Plus[y__]]] := 
 Map[Cross[vec[x], #] &, Plus[y]]
vec /: Cross[HoldPattern[Plus[y__]], vec[x_]] := 
 Map[Cross[#, vec[x]] &, Plus[y]]
scalarProduct /: MakeBoxes[scalarProduct[x_, y_], _] := 
 RowBox[{ToBoxes[x], ".", ToBoxes[y]}]

vec[x].vec[y]

(* ==> vec[x].vec[y] *)

vec[x].vec[y] == vec[y].vec[x]

(* ==> True *)

Cross[vec[x], vec[a] + vec[b]]

(* ==> vec[x]\[Cross]vec[a] + vec[x]\[Cross]vec[b] *)

Cross[vec[a] + vec[b], vec[x]]

(* ==> vec[a]\[Cross]vec[x] + vec[b]\[Cross]vec[x] *)
```

For the `Dot` product, I defined the behavior of `vec` such that it gets evaluated as a new function `scalarProduct` whose only algebraic property is that it's `Orderless` as you were expecting for the dot product of vectors. Of course this is only true for Euclidean dot products, so this assumption is implicit here. For more information on how this definition works, look up [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html).

In addition, `scalarProduct` is given a customized display format by defining that it should again display as if it were a dot product when it appears in the low-level formatting function `MakeBoxes`.

For the distributive property of the cross product, I give `vec` the additional property that when it appears in `Cross` together with an expression of head `Plus`, the sum is expanded. Here the `TagSetDelayed` definitions are done for both orders, and contain a `HoldPattern` to prevent `Plus` from being evaluated too early in the definition.

Now you may come back with many more wishes: e.g., what about multiplicative scalars in the dot or cross product, and what about matrices. However, that's a wide field that opens up a can of worms, so I would say just implement the bare minimum of features you can get away with symbolically, then proceed with a concrete working basis so that you can write vectors as lists instead.

Another approach would be to define a new symbol for a custom dot product. That is done in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17429/245).

**Using `OverVector`**

As mentioned above, you can replace `vec` by `Overvector` everywhere in the above source code, to get a better formatted result. Assuming you have done that (I won't bother to repeat the definitions with that change), here are some examples:

[image: formatted]

To enter these vector expressions, refer to the Basic Math assistant palette. The cross product can be entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd>`cross`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Another thing you asked for is to use the antisymmetry of the cross product in simplifications. That's actually done already if you invoke `FullSimplify`:

[image: antisymmetry]

Comment: Yes, the definition of new operator looks good. But it is not that convenient to use additional head. I am looking for a vector operators to simply some complicate expression involving many vectors. Is that possible to redefine +, -, . and x so don't have to use something like Plus?

Comment: Sorry, I used `Plus only because that was what I was thinking about while writing the definitions. Of course you can actually use `+` and `-` with this setup. No modifications needed at all. I also mentioned you can get a simpler format using `OverVector`, and illustrated that in an update to the answer. As to redefining `+` etc.: it's not necessary, so don't do it.

Comment: that's amazing. I never know that we can use mathematica in that way, I did learn something today. Thanks.

Comment: I find a new problem of using this definition, if I try to Cross[OverVector[x], 2*OverVector[y]] + Cross[OverVector[y], 2*OverVector[x]] but it is not zero

Comment: I already anticipated this comment in my answer, and mentioned that it opens up a wide field of additional definitions one could add. I may come back to that when I have time.

Answer (score 13):

If you have *Mathematica* Version 9, you can use `Vectors` and `TensorReduce`:

```
Assuming[(x | y) \[Element] Vectors[n] , TensorReduce[Dot[x, y] - Dot[y, x]]]
(* 0 *)
TensorReduce[Dot[x, y] - Dot[y, x], Assumptions -> (x | y) \[Element] Vectors[n]]
(* 0 *)
TensorReduce[Cross[x + y, z],  Assumptions -> (x | y | z) \[Element] Vectors[n]]
(* x\[Cross]z + y\[Cross]z *)
Distribute[Cross[x + y, z]] (* this should work in all previous versions *)
(* x\[Cross]z + y\[Cross]z *)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But what about the first one, is that possible to define an abstract row/column vector so x.y-y.x will get zero?

Comment: Presumably these solutions are for version 9 and later, when `TensorReduce` and `Vectors` were introduced.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. I updated with a note  that `TensorReduce` and `Vectors` are version-9 functions.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, I just saw that it only works on version 9 not my version 8 :(

Answer (score 2):

```
$Assumptions = (x | y) ∈ Vectors[d, Complexes]
Dot[x, y] - Dot[y, x] // TensorExpand
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this, although possibly not the best (since it can have unintended consequences), is to use

```
SetAttributes[Dot, Orderless];
```

This will make **all** dot products commute (even matrices). However, if you only happen to be working with vectors, then this is by far the cleanest way.