# How to expand a general expression in cross and dot product in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I am looking for a way to simply the general expression in cross product and dot product with general vectors. I got a help in [How do I simplify a vector expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197) but soon I find that it doesn't work in the case

```
FullSimplify[Cross[vec[x], 2*vec[y]] + Cross[vec[y], 2*vec[x]] ]
```

it doesn't give zero. It seems that *Mathematica* doesn't know how to expand the following expression

```
Cross[vec[x], 2*vec[y]] -> 2*Cross[vec[x], vec[y]]
```

Comment: You have to create some rules for instance `vec/: Cross[Times[al___,vl_vec,ar___],Times[bl___,vr_vec,br___]] := Times[al,ar,bl,br,Cross[vl,vr]]`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I try that code, but when I apply that, it reports "TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag OverVector not found in (al___\ ar___\ vl_vec)\[Cross](bl___ br___ vr_vec)"

Comment: Yes my mistake sorry, its too deep. You got to `Unprotect` `Cross` and assign the rule to `Cross` instead: `Cross[Times[al___,vl_vec,ar___],Times[bl___,vr_vec,br___]] := Times[al,ar,bl,br,Cross[vl,vr]]`

Comment: I am sorry to bother again. I try the following but it doesn't work, am I doing anything wrong? Unprotect[Cross];
Cross[Times[al___, vl_vec, ar___], Times[bl___, vr_vec, br___]] := 
 Times[al, ar, bl, br, Cross[vl, vr]]
FullSimplify[Cross[x, 2*y] + Cross[y, 2*x]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets write some simple rules for `Cross` that will work in conjunction with the object `vec`:

first of all we have to `Unprotect` the command `Cross`:

```
Unprotect[Cross]
```

to be safe because we are screwing around with a system command we save the current set of downvalues to a temporary varaiable:

```
temp = DownValues[Cross]
```

we begin with a rule for the skew-symmetric property:

```
Cross[vl_vec,vr_vec]/;!OrderedQ[{vl,vr}] := -Cross[vr,vl]
```

we continue for the multiplication by a scalar rule

```
Cross[Times[al__, vl_vec], vr_vec] := Times[al, Cross[vl, vr]] 
Cross[vl_vec,Times[al__, vr_vec]] := Times[al, Cross[vl, vr]] 
Cross[Times[al__ ,vl_vec],Times[bl__, vr_vec]] := Times[al, bl, Cross[vl, vr]]
```

I split them in two in order to cover the case Cross[vec[x],2*vec[y]] for instance where one of the is not multiplied by a scalar.
Now the command

```
Cross[vec[x], 2*vec[y]] + Cross[2*vec[y], vec[x]]
```

will give

> 0

to return everything the way thy were:

```
DownValues[Cross] = temp
```

or just `Quit` the Kernel.

Comment: Rather than unprotecting `Cross[]`, it is usually better to use `TagSet[]`/`TagSetDelayed[]` associated with `vec[]`. For instance, here's the flipping rule: `vec /: Cross[v1_vec, v2_vec] /; ! OrderedQ[{v1, v2}] := -Cross[v2, v1]`. Now, try `Cross[vec[y], vec[x]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Its too deep, not for this rule but the following ones.

Comment: How so? If you add `vec /: Cross[Times[al__, vl_vec], vr_vec] := Times[al, Cross[vl, vr]]` and then do `Cross[3 vec[y], vec[x]]`, it still works.

Comment: @J.M. look the comments with the OP and you will understand why I thought so.

Comment: Apparently, there's something wrong with his implementation of `vec[]`, since `TagSet[]` is seeing it as an `OverVector[]` object. I think an answer is in order...

Comment: @J.M. probably he wrote the vector using the mathematical notation for it, nevertheless the suggestion I gave him, in that form, has problem - OverVector or not OverVector present.

Comment: thanks all. it works up to now. I am just wonder how to apply these to complicate expression like Dot[vec[x], Cross[vec[y], vec[z]]] + Dot[vec[x], Cross[vec[y], vec[x]]] ?

Comment: @user1285419 in the same fashion you can add the properties of `Dot` and `Cross` you want. For instance `vec/:Dot[a:_vec, Cross[_, a:_vec]|Cross[a:_vec, _]] = 0`. Depends on what you want to implement.

Comment: @Spawn1701D thanks. I am just wondering if there is any way to include all possible combinations of operations instead of define each of them individually

Comment: Like a student Mathematica must be taught ;)

Comment: So Cross[a vec[x], vec[y]] works, Cross[vec[x], b vec[y]] works but Cross[a vec[x], b vec[y]] doesn't work :(

Comment: @user1285419 indeed thats why first I attached the rule to `Outer`.

Comment: @user1285419 I revert back to my initial answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) and [`Vectors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Vectors):

```
$Assumptions = Element[vec[x] | vec[y], Vectors[{n}]];

TensorReduce[Cross[vec[x],2*vec[y]]+Cross[vec[y],2*vec[x]]]
```

> 0

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems you want your `vec[]` objects to be nicely formatted, here's one way to go about it:

```
Remove[vec]; (* clear everything!! *)

vec /: MakeBoxes[vec[x_], StandardForm] := TagBox[FormBox[
              TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]}, "vec",
                          DisplayFunction :> (OverscriptBox[#1, "⇀"] &)],
              StandardForm], StandardForm, Editable -> True]
```

Now, `vec[x]` will display as $\overset{\tiny\rightharpoonup}{x}$ in `StandardForm`. Having done this, we can again do Spawn's initial suggestion to use `TagSetDelayed[]`:

```
vec /: Cross[v1_vec, v2_vec] /; ! OrderedQ[{v1, v2}] := -Cross[v2, v1];
vec /: Cross[p_ v1_vec, v2_vec] := p Cross[v1, v2];
vec /: Cross[v1_vec, q_ v2_vec] := q Cross[v1, v2];
```

Test:

[image: samples of vec's behavior]