# How do I avoid vector variables being treated as scalars in the course of replacements?

Tags: replacement, vector

I often work with a mixture of symbolic and concrete values as I develop teaching materials.  I introduce variables symbolically and then need to instantiate them to specific values while continuing to use the original variables. My `i` represents a vector `{1, 0, 0}` but I don't want to replace `i` with `{1, 0, 0}` *everywhere*, just when convenient.  Thus I lit upon the idea of using replacement rules rather than definitions. But things didn't work out too well:

```
{a, a + b} //. {a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}, i -> {1, 0, 0}}
(* output: {{4, 0, 0}, {{4, 0, 0}, {2, -2, -2}, {6, 2, 2}}} *)
```

while I wanted this result instead:

```
{a /. {a -> 4 i}, (a /. {a -> 4 i}) + b} //. {b -> {0, -2, 2}, i -> {1, 0, 0}}
(* output: {{4, 0, 0}, {4, -2, 2}} *)
```

I now understand that `4 i` is treated as a constant in rewriting `a + b`:

```
{a, a + b} /. {a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}}
(* output: {4 i, {4 i, -2 + 4 i, 2 + 4 i}} *)
```

I could attempt to control the substitution order by doing something like

```
{a, a + b} //. ({a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}} /. i -> {1, 0, 0}) //. {i -> {1, 0, 0}}
(* output: {{4, 0, 0}, {4, -2, 2}} *)
```

But this is not very robust and won't work if substitutions are nested more deeply.

I can prevent premature application of the problematic rule using conditions e.g.

```
{a, a + b} //. {a :> 4 i /; i ∈ Vectors[v], b -> {0, -2, 2}, i -> {1, 0, 0}}
```

But then the rule never gets used as the RHS of the rule is never rewritten.

I don't really want to recast all the vector operators I might need following the example of
[this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21203/4811); this seems like overkill.
But I do already use a wrapper `bv[i]` which prints as `UnderBar[i]`.  Can anyone suggest a lightweight solution?  Could I make `Plus`, `Times` etc. (temporarily) *un*-listable?

BTW This issue is flagged in the documentation for `Assuming`, which does not help in this situation as `Plus` just goes ahead and uses its `Listable` attribute:

```
Assuming[v ∈ Vectors[2], v + {1, 2}]
(* output: {1 + v, 2 + v} *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `i` replacement first for other rules:

```
{a, a + b} /. ({a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}} /. i -> {1, 0, 0})
```

> ```
> {{4, 0, 0}, {4, -2, 2}}
> ```

---

Or even your first way will do if you `Hold` on for a while :)

```
Hold[{a, a + b}] //. {a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}, i -> {1, 0, 0}} // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {{4, 0, 0}, {4, -2, 2}}
> ```

but here I'd choose to make second replacement instead of `ReplaceRepeted`:

```
Hold[{a, a + b}] /. {a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}} /. i -> {1, 0, 0} // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {{4, 0, 0}, {4, -2, 2}}
> ```

Comment: yes; I think I covered that; the problem with that approach is that it is hard to predict in advance how much of such manipulations will be needed: they will need to match the depth of nesting of substitutions.

Comment: @fairflow have you tried `Hold` approach with your more complicated examples? I must say I don't know what do you need to predict here, could you explain further?

Comment: Sorry, I posted my comment before you'd added to your answer and then my edit window timed out.  `Hold` is good, don't know why I didn't think of that, probably forgot replacements work inside `Hold`s.  And I take your point about `ReplaceAll` instead of `ReplaceRepeated` but my example was artificially simplified and in general I need the repeats.

Comment: @fairflow Ok :) I'm glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily change the attributes of a function within `Block`:

```
Block[{
  Plus = Plus,
  Times = Times},
 Attributes[Plus] = {};
 Attributes[Times] = {};
 {a, a + b} //. {a -> 4 i, b -> {0, -2, 2}, i -> {1, 0, 0}}
 ]
```

Careful what you put inside though, as that temporary override will trickle into all functions inside too.

Comment: Nice trick, redefining `Plus` and `Times` as...themselves!  So the attribute changes are shadowed and don't persist outside the `Block`.  This might do it for me, though the `Hold` solution seems simpler.