# Cross product of three vectors

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

I am following the answer of Jens from following post:
[How do I simplify a vector expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197/how-do-i-simplify-a-vector-expression/21203#21203)

```
vec /: Cross[vec[x_], HoldPattern[Cross[y__]]] :=
```

I want to create following identities (I use `x` to represent `\[Cross]` for readability):

```
vec[a]x(vec[b] x vec[c]) = (vec[a] x vec[b]) x vec[c] - (vec[a] x vec[c]) x vec[b]

(vec[a] x vec[b]) x vec[c] = vec[a] x (vec[b] x vec[c]) + (vec[a] x vec[c]) x vec[b]
```

but unable to make. I tried the following command `Map[Cross[Cross[vec[x], #], #] &, Plus[y]]` but in product it gives

```
vec[a]x(vec[b] x vec[c]) = (vec[a] x vec[b]) x vec[b] - (vec[a] x vec[c]) x vec[c]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you can't input a simple `x`-character and expect that to be the operator for cross product.

Comment: Hi! I have shared the link of the an answer that I am following. I didn't copy the whole procedure as it might b bulky. I am sharing again here: [Answer by Jens](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197/how-do-i-simplify-a-vector-expression) . Please look into first answer by Jens

Comment: @aly I incorporated your comment into the body of the question, since the `x` was causing confusion.  I think it's fine the way it is, but one thing to keep in mind is that people using the site usually have *M* running and can copy and paste ugly code into the front end to see it formatted nicely and have the syntax checked.  The question is whether having the desired code with proper syntax is helpful to those who are interested in your question.  It might seem so to some, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

To implement your first identity you can use:

```
vec /: Cross[vec[x_], Cross[vec[y_], vec[z_]]] := 
 Cross[Cross[vec@x, vec@y], vec@z] -Cross[Cross[vec@x, vec@z], vec@y]
```

Resulting in:

```
In[1] := vec[x]\[Cross](vec[y]\[Cross]vec[z])
Out[1] = (vec[x]\[Cross]vec[y])\[Cross]vec[z] - (vec[x]\[Cross]vec[z])\[Cross]vec[y]
```

The other identity is implemented similarly

Comment: Instead of Dot it will be cross. I changed it and works fine with me. Thanks gIS

Comment: @aly of course! Sorry for the typo, `Dot` would not even make sense as it generates a scalar.

Comment: @gIS: I extended your suggestion and trying to implement this `vec /: Cross[Cross[vec[x_], vec[y_]], Cross[vec[x_], vec[z_]]] := 
 Cross[vec@x, Cross[vec@y, Cross[vec@x, vec@z]]] - 
  Cross[vec@y, Cross[vec@x, Cross[vec@x, vec@z]]]` but it gives error "Tag vec in (vec[x_]\[Cross]vec[y_])\[Cross](vec[x_]\[Cross]vec[z_]) \
is too deep for an assigned rule to be found."