# Defining UpValue like replacements confined to exprs with specific Head

Tags: replacement, upvalues

I'm not seeing a clean method to redefine builtin functions like Cross, Dot, etc. in such a way they only are only applied to expressions that are using some marker-like Head value.  Reduced example, let's say I'm using `Foo[..]` as a head to represents some pair of expression.  The pair of expressions inside a Foo might be involved so making explicit patterns doesn't go very far.  Basically I'm looking to do something like this non-working example:

```
Foo /: Cross[v_, v_] := 0;
```

#### update 1

Trivial example is symbolically reducing quaternions over reals. One rule for the product looks like:

```
realQuat /: 
 NonCommutativeMultiply[realQuat[L_, l_], realQuat[R_, r_]] := 
 realQuat[Cross[L,R] + l R + r L, r l - Dot[L,R]]
```

So with a pair written as a (bi)vector scalar pair without Cross reduction:

```
t0 = realQuat[A,a];
t1 = realQuat[A,b];
t0**t1
```

gives:

```
realQuat[a A + A b + AxA, a b - A.A]
```

instead of the `Cross` term dropping out like this:

```
realQuat[a A + A b, a b - A.A]
```

(this is a strawman example)

#### attempt using TensorReduce

Starting from the suggesting of using TensorReduce, I tossed together two containers to mark symbols as either elements of R3 or R, basic funcs to add to both and a reduction function.  Much cleaner than my previous attempts.

```
realQuatB = Alternates[]; (* for marking R3 symbols *)
realQuatS = Alternates[]; (* for marking R symbols *)
realQuatDefB[x_] := If[!MemberQ[realQuatB,x],AppendTo[realQuatB,x];];
realQuatDefS[x_] := If[!MemberQ[realQuatS,x],AppendTo[realQuatS,x];];
SetAttributes[realQuatDefB, {Listable}];
SetAttributes[realQuatDefS, {Listable}];

realQuat /: rqReduce[realQuat[Q_,q_]] := realQuat[
  TensorReduce[Q, Assumptions->Element[realQuatB,Vectors[3,Reals]] &&
     Element[realQuatS,Reals]],
  TensorReduce[q, Assumptions->Element[realQuatB,Vectors[3,Reals]] &&
     Element[realQuatS,Reals]]];
```

Comment: You could Block and Unprotect Cross, could you show a  small example of input and expected output?

Comment: Added an example to help clarify.

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking, and what this has to do with `UpValues`.  What do you expect as the output?  Please give a concrete example, complete with example input, actual output (you have both) and desired output (you don't have this).

Comment: Like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197/how-do-i-simplify-a-vector-expression/ -- E.g. `TensorReduce[Cross[A, A], Assumptions -> A \[Element] Vectors[n]]`

Comment: @ Szabolcs: By "UpValue" like I was intending to say we can use a marker head and upvalue defs to scope when some rules are applied and I'm generally curious if there a simply method to have rules applied at any sub-expression level of a maker head.

Comment: @ Michael E2:  Using TensorReduce never occurred to me.  The hacked example above is much cleaner that my previous hacks.