# Basic simplifications in vector algebra

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

Newish Mathematica user here! I just learned about the built-in vector type. To experiment with it I tried to specify that $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and I hoped that Mathematica would simplify $(2a+3b)\cdot (2a-3b)$ to yield $4a\cdot a- 9 b \cdot b$.

```
$Assumptions = 
  a \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals] && b \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals];
(2 a + 3 b ) . (2 a - 3 b) // Expand
```

Unfortunately I only see "(2 a + 3 b).(2 a - 3 b)" in the answer.  I am aware of the related question [How do I simplify a vector expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21197/how-do-i-simplify-a-vector-expression/21203#21203) but I don't want to create my own "vec" object. I would rather use the built-in Vector[3,Reals] object if this is possible. The actual application will have many vectors and lengthy symbolic (scalar) expressions instead of integer coefficients.

Comment: You just need `TensorExpand`.