# Raising, lowering and number operators for Dirac notation

Tags: physics, operators

Starting from this very interesting post [Defining quantum-mechanical Bra and Ket operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84619/defining-quantum-mechanical-bra-and-ket-operations), i would like to implement raising, lowering and number operators, taking into account that they might be non-commutative, i.e.
$$
  a_i^\dagger a_i |n_1,\dots ,n_i, \dots \rangle \neq a_i a_i^\dagger |n_1,\dots ,n_i, \dots \rangle
$$
I know that there is a package for Quantum Mechanics but I would prefer a stand-alone script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SNEG library](http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/) is a (now fairly old) package for second-quantised operators, especially in the context of condensed matter physics.  It's sometimes a bit clunky, but I still occasionally find it useful.

Comment: Can you maybe give a short example on how to use the package?