# What are current approaches for supporting Dirac notation for quantum mechanics?

Tags: matrix, vector, physics, operators, custom-notation

I'd like to be able to use Mathematica to preform some basic quantum mechanics and quantum computation operations using Dirac's Bra-Ket notation.

I've seen [several](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84619/37) [solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17429/37) to defining basic behaviors, and can roll my own with something rudimentary that takes lists of components expressed in a fixed basis, like

```
Bra[1]=Bra[{1,0}];Ket[1]=Ket[{1,0}];
Bra[0]=Bra[{0,1}];Ket[0]=Ket[{0,1}];
Bra[l_]:={Conjugate[l]}
Ket[l_]:=Transpose@{l}
AngleBracket[0,y_]:=0
AngleBracket[x_,0]:=0
AngleBracket[x_,y_]:=Bra[x].Ket[y]//First//First
Clear[VerticalSeparator]
AngleBracket[bra___,VerticalSeparator[x_,y_],ket___]:=AngleBracket[x,y]
```

But this only goes so far. For example I'd minimally also like to implement outer products

$$\left|u\right>\left<v\right|$$

basic tensor notation

$$\left|u\right>\otimes\left|v\right>\otimes\left|w\right>\equiv\left|u,v,w\right>\equiv\left|uvw\right>$$

and the key properties of bras and kets — e.g. ($\left|u\right>)^*=\left<v\right|$.

Ideally I'd like more, such as factoring and decomposition, or easy change of bases.

I also understand that there are [some sophisticated packages](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/) that do all this and more. But these seem to be far more complex than I need, and are also quite old (and produce odd formatting that makes me wonder if they can even be relied on in the current version of MMA (the latest version mentioned for QUANTUM in 8).

There are two possible solutions I'd be interested in:

1. Are there simple things I can do myself, e.g., extending the rudimentary start I've made above, that will get me most of what I want?
2. Is there a more recent comprehensive package stable current package available than [QUANTUM](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/). (Alternatively perhaps someone can confirm that QUANTUM works error-free with v.11; and can help fix the odd formatting of bras and kets.)

Truth be told, I'd prefer the former solution, to keep things simple and to avoid introducing too many definitions and redefinitions; but I'd also be interested in the latter if a current easy to use and well documented package is available.

---

Using [`Notation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) I can get something started with

```
<<Notation`
Notation[|1\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] |{1,0}\[RightAngleBracket]];Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]1| \[DoubleLongRightArrow] \[LeftAngleBracket]{1,0}|];
Notation[|0\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] |{0,1}\[RightAngleBracket]];Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]0| \[DoubleLongRightArrow] \[LeftAngleBracket]{0,1}|];
Notation[|x_\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] Transpose@{x_}]
Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]y_| \[DoubleLongRightArrow] {Conjugate[y_]}]
Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]x_\[VerticalSeparator]y_\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] \[LeftAngleBracket]x_|.|y_\[RightAngleBracket]]
Notation[|x_\[RightAngleBracket]\[LeftAngleBracket]y_| \[DoubleLongRightArrow] |x_\[RightAngleBracket].\[LeftAngleBracket]y_|]
```

(It looks neater in MMA.)

Comment: One question: why are you mucking around with `AngleBracket`? There's the symbol `BraKet` which you could work with instead. And `[esc]bra[esc]` will give you a `Bra` to work with, `[esc]ket[esc]` will give you a `Ket`, and `[esc]brakey[esc]` will give you a `BraKet`.

Comment: @b3m2a1: `Notation` looks interesting.

Comment: In this case it's not needed though. I've got something in the works that will hopefully get you on a better path.

Comment: @b3m2a1: I don't know — `Notation` looks pretty cool (see addition to Q).

Comment: I mean you can do it, but you lose the benefits of working with a symbolic language. The best thing to do here is to leave everything unevaluated until you apply some evaluator function. That way you can work with bras and kets and bra-kets as symbolic objects.

Comment: @b3m2a1: Seems like some use of `Notation` is appropriate though, no (or am I missing its limitations)?

Comment: The two main limitations are that 1) it's basically just a box form (though that doesn't matter two much) 2) everything evaluates immediately so you can't attach more complex evaluation semantics to things; you really want, e.g., `Ket[___]` to only evaluate at the very end. Anytime before that things like the outer-product rule won't work.

Comment: b3m2a1: Yes, exactly. I see that now: I tried to get tensor product representations to work and hit a dead end. Though I'd have thought that the right approach then would be to define regular functions (with `:=`) that have the needed rich semantics and then just wrap the functions in the pretty notation, using `Notation` (but I may still be missing something).

Comment: See my answer for *a* way to do this. Obviously this is Mathematica so there are many ways to do it.

Comment: @b3m2a1: For example `bra[f_,r__]:=bra[f]⊗ bra[r];
Notation[|x_ 〉  ⟺ bra[x_]]`.

Comment: Hey OP, I totally agree with you that some packages out there are too complicated to use. I made my own here https://github.com/bernie-wu/BernDirac and it is quite similar to what you described in your post. However, it only supports 0s and 1s as input to Ket and Bra for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So Mathematica will actually handle most of this formatting for us, so the question then is how do we want to handle setting the rules.

Since Mathematica is a symbolic language I think it's best to keep things as symbolic as possible. Because of that what we'll do is register our own evaluation rules to be applied once we've done all the symbolic manipulation we want.

We'll set up rules on a function `BraKetRule`, and we'll apply them with `BraKetEval`. To make setting these more convenient we'll use two functions `BraKetAlias` and `BraKetAliasCore` (the latter will remain unevaluated until the last step) that will look like this:

```
ClearAll[BraKetAlias];
BraKetAlias[HoldPattern[SetDelayed[x_, y_]]] :=

  SetDelayed[BraKetRule[x], y];
BraKetAlias[
   e__] :=
  {BraKetAlias /@ HoldComplete[e] // ReleaseHold};
BraKetAlias[{exprs___}] :=
  BraKetAlias[exprs];
BraKetAlias[HoldPattern[CompoundExpression[e__]]] :=

  BraKetAlias[e];
BraKetAlias[Null] := Null;
BraKetAlias~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;

ClearAll[BraKetAliasCore];
BraKetAliasCore[HoldPattern[SetDelayed[x_, y_]]] :=

  SetDelayed[BraKetRule[x] /; TrueQ[$eBraKet], y];
BraKetAliasCore[
   e__] :=
  {BraKetAliasCore /@ HoldComplete[e] // ReleaseHold};
BraKetAliasCore[{exprs___}] :=
  BraKetAliasCore[exprs];
BraKetAliasCore[HoldPattern[CompoundExpression[e__]]] :=

  BraKetAliasCore[e];
BraKetAliasCore[Null] := Null;
BraKetAliasCore~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

Then we set up our rules:

```
Clear[BraKetRule];
BraKetAliasCore[
  Bra[1] := BraKetRule@Bra[{1, 0}];
  Ket[1] := BraKetRule@Ket[{1, 0}];
  Bra[0] := BraKetRule@Bra[{0, 1}];
  Ket[0] := BraKetRule@Ket[{0, 1}];
  Bra[l_] := {Conjugate[Flatten[{l}, 1]]};
  Ket[l_] := Transpose@{Flatten[{l}, 1]};
  BraKet[0, y_] := 0;
  BraKet[x_, 0] := 0;
  BraKet[x_, y_] := Bra[x].Ket[y] // First // First;
  ];
BraKetAlias[
  NonCommutativeMultiply[Ket[y_], Bra[x_]] :=

   With[{f = Flatten[{x}, 1]},
    NonCommutativeMultiply[BraKet[f, {#}], Bra[y]] &
    ];
  CircleTimes[k__Ket] :=
   Thread[Times[k], Ket];
  Conjugate[Ket[v_]] :=
   Bra[Conjugate[v]];
  ];
BraKetRule[e_] := e;
```

(Note the use of [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html). That's important.)

Then here are some rules that we'll set on `Bra`, `Ket`, and `BraKet` themselves for convenience:

```
Clear[Bra, Ket, BraKet];
Times[Bra[x_], Ket[y_]] ^:= BraKet[x, y];
BraKet[x : Except[_List], y_] := BraKet[{x}, y];
BraKet[x_, y : Except[_List]] := BraKet[x, {y}];
```

And finally our little `BraKetEval` function:

```
Clear[BraKetEval];
BraKetEval[e_] :=
 With[{base = BraKetRule //@ e},
  Block[{$eBraKet = True},
    base /. {
      r : (_Bra | _Ket | _BraKet) :> BraKetRule[r]
      }
    ] /. HoldPattern[BraKetRule[r_]] :> r
  ]
```

Now we can handle all this junk symbolically.

First make a `Bra`, `Ket`, or `BraKet` with `[esc]bra[esc]`, `[esc]ket[esc]`, or `[esc]braket[esc]` respectively (note that `[tab]` will move you to the place holders).

Then you can do junk like:

```
Bra[1] Ket[1]

BraKet[{1}, {1}]
```

Or

```
Ket[1] ** Bra[1] // BraKetEval

BraKet[{1}, {#1}] ** Bra[1] &
```

Or

```
Ket[f]⊗Ket[g]⊗Ket[h] // BraKetEval

{{f g h}}

Ket[1]⊗Ket[1]⊗Ket[1] // BraKetEval

{{1}, {0}}
```

---

#### BraKetEval Cells

We can make this somewhat more convenient by defining a cell type that will auto-eval using `BraKetEval`:

```
Options[BraKetCell] =
  Join[
   Options[NotebookWrite],
   Options[Cell]
   ];
BraKetCell[
  nb : _CellObject | _NotebookObject | Automatic : Automatic,
  e : Except[_?OptionQ] : Automatic,
  sel : Except[_?OptionQ] : Before,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 With[{obj = Replace[nb, Automatic :> InputNotebook[]]},
  NotebookWrite[obj,
   Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Replace[e, Automatic :> Placeholder[]],
    "BraKetCell",
    "Input",
    Sequence @@
     FilterRules[{
       ops,
       InputAutoReplacements -> {
         ParentList,
         "bra" -> TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]"}, "Bra"],
         "ket" -> TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]"}, "Ket"],
         "braket" -> 
          TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "BraKet"]
         },
       CellEvaluationFunction -> BraKetEval@*ToExpression
       },
      Options[Cell]
      ]
    ],
   sel,
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{ops}, Options[NotebookWrite]]
   ]
  ]
```

It also uses `bra` and `ket`, and `braket` as `InputAutoReplacements` for convenience.

Then it's just used like this:

```
BraKetCell[]

Bra[1] 

{{1, 0}}

BraKetCell[]

Ket[2]

{{2}}

BraKetCell[]

BraKet[{f}, {g}]

f
```

You could add it as a style to a stylesheet too, for even greater convenience.

Comment: Can I define the following ket using your code?https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230931/quantum-bra-and-ket-notations

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title, there is the fully open-sourced and free-to-use [BernDirac](https://github.com/bernie-wu/BernDirac) package on Github which I implemented myself. The documentation is fully laid out on the [readme](https://github.com/bernie-wu/BernDirac/blob/main/README.md) page.

This package does not have any dependencies and is quite lightweight and simple to use compared to the ones you linked.

It uses the built-in Ket and Bra operator and the notation is quite similar to what you described, but it only supports 0's and 1's as input for now.

Since this is open source, you can dig into my fairly-short [code](https://github.com/bernie-wu/BernDirac/blob/main/BernDirac.wl) and hopefully you can figure out how to implement what you want or even improve on it.