# Dirac Bra Ket notation in Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra

I am using Mathematica 10.0. Trying to run the following `` Needs["Quantum`Notation`"] `` in order to use Dirac notation. But it shows

> Get::noopen: Cannot open Quantum`Notation`.

What should be done get this thing working?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install this package. You can download it [here](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/#download), and there are instructions on how to install it on the same page.

If you allow me a personal comment: I tried it a couple of years ago and didn't like it. In my opinion it only adds a lot of overhead that can cause problems where you could just use Mathematica built-in features (what are you doing other than linear algebra?), which are more reliable, better documented and well-known so it's easier to find support.

Comment: I am actually interested in doing the quantum walk problem using Mathematica. I found some information from an online source which uses the package mentioned in my question.

Comment: cool. ok in this case you want to install the package to use that source. And when you run into problems with the notation you can easily move to standard matrix functions. Are you aware of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155765/what-are-current-approaches-for-supporting-dirac-notation-for-quantum-mechanics), btw.?

Comment: Thanks, @M. Stern. It is really helpful.

Comment: Hello @M.Stern. Can I get your email?

Comment: I'd rather not post my email here.. but if you want to post contact information (maybe in your profile) I can give you my email that way

Comment: Could you contact me at jan1002@rediffmail.com ?